# WPF TextBox Wrap everywhere in string

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, word-wrap

I have a `TextBox` in a WPF project that contains a complex Regex pattern like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbPattern" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Consolas"
    Text="^(?type>([A-Z]|[0-9])+)_(?Y>\d{4})(?M>0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?d>0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])_(?H>([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]))(?m>([0-5][0-9]))(?s>([0-5][0-9]))(~(?n>[1-9][0-9]*))?\.(?ext>([A-Z|a-z|0-9]+))$"
/>
```

(Yes, the regex syntax is invalid, but it's only for testing purpose...)

Because the pattern is not expected to contain many spaces, I would like to wrap the text box text always at the end of the line, ignoring space characters before, like command inputs use to do it (simply open cmd and insert the pattern. In each line, all characters will range up to the last column).

So I tested available `TextWrapping` properties but could not found the right one. `NoWrap` produces some very chaotic display, while simple `Wrap` option distributes the pattern over non-equally long lines. This is also done by `WrapWithOverflow`.

How can I use a wrapping algorithm in cmd style that does not search for spaces to earlier breaking line? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace space to non-breaking space.

```
Replace(" ", "\u00a0")
```

And you can bind replaced value via a property for preserve the original text. Or you can also use a converter.

Comment: Okay, but doesn't this change the user's input? If he or she copies the pattern from the text box to another program, the clipboard will not contain the original text, will it? I'm afraid that sounds not maximally user friendly.